# offline navigation with public transportation

Tags: gps, google-maps-navigation, maps, navigation, offline-map

I can not drive (yet) and I get lost pretty easily.
So, I need a simple navigation app (I like the gmaps look, just roads, no fancy colors and things), which includes ALL bus/tram/metro/train (yeap, all of them) stations of greece, their schedule and navigation through them.
I NEED it to be offline, otherwise, I would use my favorite gmaps. Cellural data here cost A LOT (I have only 60MB/mo).
I've tested nearly each and every navigation app out there.
I don't care about the cost, but being free is a plus, especially open source.
I can extract the points of bus stations (I think) from the maps provided by greece.
I can also extract the schedules, but i don't know in which format.

thank you!
I've searched the whole web and I found no answer...

Comment: Have you tried Osmand~?

Comment: yes. very weird maps and no punlic transportation support

Comment: hmm, it seems it has public transit support, but no routing and not enough bus stops.if this is my only choice... also how/can i import bus stops from gmaps?

Comment: You can edit OpenStreetmap yourself to add any information that's missing. As for the routing data, this will only be possible if the public transport operators allow you to download and freely reproduce the timetables and route plans.

Comment: How can i do that? Here are all the timetables (http://www.oasa.gr/routes.php?id=lines_name_1)

Comment: I think I can extract them with a script. but in which format? how can i import them?